# Is Pearson correlation faster than Spearman correlation in R?

Tags: r, performance, correlation, pearson-correlation, pearson

I would like to determine many correlations (millions) between pairs of columns, so I am worried about computing time.

I suspect that Pearson correlations (based on values) are faster to calculate in R than Spearman correlations (based on ranks). Is that correct?

How can I find out, please? Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the dimension of your data?

Comment: Sure, I have two matrices, one with ~2,000 columns x 100 rows and one with ~6,000 columns x 1000 rows. Row ids match. My code intends to calculate Spearman (or Pearson) correlations between all possible pairs of columns in matrix 1 and columns in matrix 2. Total about 12,000,000 Spearman or Pearson correlations to calculate. Thank you.

Comment: You might find this interesting https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8071/how-to-choose-between-pearson-and-spearman-correlation

Comment: I like this post, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `rbenchmark` package for this.

```r
library(rbenchmark)
```

1.000 rows, 100 repetitions

```r
x1 <- rnorm(1000)
y1 <- rnorm(1000)

benchmark(spearman = {
  cor(x1, y1, method = "spearman")
},
pearson = {
  cor(x1, y1, method = "pearson")
},
replications = 100)
#>       test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child
#> 2  pearson          100   0.002        1     0.002        0          0
#> 1 spearman          100   0.014        7     0.013        0          0
#>   sys.child
#> 2         0
#> 1         0
```

1.000.000 rows, 100 repititions

```r
x2 <- rnorm(1000000)
y2 <- rnorm(1000000)

benchmark(spearman = {
  cor(x2, y2, method = "spearman")
},
pearson = {
  cor(x2, y2, method = "pearson")
},
replications = 100)
#>       test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child
#> 2  pearson          100   0.717    1.000     0.717    0.001          0
#> 1 spearman          100  37.336   52.073    36.797    0.537          0
#>   sys.child
#> 2         0
#> 1         0
```

This confirms you assumption: Pearson is significantly faster than Spearman.
Especially when the rows/cases are increased, Spearman becomes slow.

Comment: I think there are faster methods available, implemented in external packages.

Comment: Can you provide package names or urls? The examples above can easily be modified to use any other function OP might consider.

Comment: Thank you, Till! You are right, this makes a big difference with increasing numbers. :)